Preview file with custom extension on Preview Pane of File Explorer
I want to show the preview of a file with a custom extension.
The file contains:

a binary struct that has some details that i would like to show in the details pane.
an array of byte that is basically a BMP (i have the size of this array because its saved in the binary struct that i mentioned before) that i want to display in the preview pane.
plain text such xml (not used, ignored)

any help is welcome!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
